# Do not attempt to start gdb on SIGSEGV

Tags: bash, segmentation-fault, gdb, gstreamer

How can I prevent my system from trying to start gdb in case of SIGSEGV? I want my application to die properly, so the return of the process can be caught and errors (if any) handled properly.

> Caught SIGSEGV
> exec gdb failed: No such file or directory
> Spinning.  Please run 'gdb gst-launch-1.0 1586' to continue debugging, Ctrl-C to quit, or Ctrl-\ to dump core.
> ^C|^\Quit

Comment: It would be helpful to update the question with an explanation (or a tag, if nothing else) for why "your system" is invoking `gdb` automatically at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GStreamer program that is started by [gst-launch](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gst-launch-0.10.1.html) will, by default, install a *fault handler* function as the signal handler for SIGSEGV and SIGQUIT. When either of those signals arrive, the program will run GDB to display a stack trace - in your case, GDB wasn't found - then go into a low-overhead spin loop while waiting for you to run GDB manually. ([Source code](https://fossies.org/linux/gstreamer/tools/gst-launch.c#l_122).)

You can prevent the fault handler from being installed by giving `gst-launch` the `--no-fault` or `-f` option.